# .htaccess permanent redirection with condition

Tags: htaccess, redirects

I want to redirect ONLY users from website1 pages to website2 homepage. The google bot and other crawlers must indexing and do not know about redirection. Can you help me?

I know how to place the permanent redirect, but how to add a condition to be only for users?

**Edited:**

I want to redirect the whole website to another one with `.htaccess`. The redirect must be valid only for visitors without web crawlers and bots. I want the Googlebot and other crawlers to continue indexing and viewing the old website without being redirected.

For example, if I put:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www.website1.com [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^website1.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website2.com/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

In the `.htaccess` file, all visitors from website1 will be redirected to website2 homepage. Robots and search engines will continue to index without being redirected to website2?

Comment: You know that's bad SEO right? Trying to trick Google into seeing a different website than humans is just asking for a penalty.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But what is the way to create the condition for the redirect?

Comment: If you update your question with an explanation of *why* you want to do this, then you may get some useful answers.